# Create new tmux session inside a session with default path and name

Tags: tmux

I can create a new session inside a session using this command `<leader> :new`. We can change the name later using `<leader> $`. Is there a way to define the name of that session when we create it and can we change the default directory of new created window in that session ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

> new-session [-AdDEP] [-c start-directory] [-F format] [-n window-name] [-s session-name] [-t group-name] [-x width] [-y height] [shell-command] (alias: new) Create a new session with name session-name.

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the  -s and -c options.